Coredump file not generating
Suddenly my postgresql service started crashing for some reason.
I wanted to generate coredump file but file is not generating.
I set: "ulimit -S -c unlimited", also added line "*soft core unlimited" to /etc/security/limits.conf.
Also set my destination dir to kernel.core_pattern="/coredumps/core-%e-%s-%u-%g-%p-%t".
Also executed "chmod 777" to destination path to eliminate permission issues.
I was able to generate test coredump file by executing "perl -MPOSIX -e '$0="ttt"; pause' &" and then running "kill -ABRT " and file got saved to /coredumps with correct filename.
When my postgres crashes i can see in logs:
Resource limits disable core dumping for process 3607766 (postmaster).
Process 3607766 (postmaster) of user 26 dumped core.
systemd-coredump@13-140614-0.service: Succeeded.
Also i noticed difference between outputs of "cat /proc/pid/limits" between my test process and postgres.
Test process has "Max core file size" set to "unlimited" and postgresql value "0"


Have you tried adding LimitCORE=infinity to the [service] section of the postgress unit file?

Limits are not system-wide – they are per-process, initialized and inherited similar to environment variables. Your ulimit command therefore only raises the coredump limit for the Bash instance you're entering that command in – not for anyone else and not for any service.
The limits are initialized from /etc/security/limits.conf for user logins; however, on Linux, services don't go through the "user login" procedure even if they have a service account, so the limit initialization from /etc/security will not occur.
Instead all such limits need to be set through the service manager which starts Postgres – in this case systemd, so you need to use systemctl edit to add the LimitCORE= option to the .service file.
Alternatively, you can use the prlimit command to change the resource limits of an already running process, assuming it can still run for a short while before it crashes.
